# Alternative way to clean or discard a question draft?

Tags: support, questions, draft

When asking a new question, I have pasted a huge block of code mistakenly. Now, when I open **stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**, I cannot clean the question body, because the page never ends loading. That draft is always loaded.

How can I solve this problem? I have cleaned the browser history, opened StackOverflow in other browser, but the site is the responsible for maintaining the draft for me. **PS. I cannot click the discard button.**

Comment: I just made a question larger than the 30,000 characters permitted, no problem with discarding it. What language? Was it just code, or does it contain links? The coloured highlighting stuff? Or what? If you stop the loading, can you edit the question?

Comment: The code I have pasted has 502913 characters. It is a `img` tag with a `data:url`.

Comment: Wow. Perhaps you'll need an SE Developer to assist you. Someone may know a good chatroom or something.

Comment: Firefox shows a warning of an unresponsive script. If I choose 'Stop script', the question textarea options turn disabled and even if I erase that content, it has no effect.

Comment: have you tried going through the dev tools and clearing the data from there? (that is, if stopping the page loading allows you to go that far)

Comment: @jbutler483 I'm trying to do what you mentioned too, but the browser gets totally blocked after some seconds.

Comment: The draft will be discarded after a few days, so you could just wait a while.

Comment: @Servy I suppose setting the clock forward is less of a workaround these days...

Comment: @BillWoodger Of course, it's SE's sever clock that needs to be set forward, not your local clock, so unless you get admin access to their servers or have a time machine, you'll need to use the old fashioned method of time travel: waiting.

Comment: @Servy at least that's the great thing about time travel. It doesn't matter how many years it takes me to perfect it, I'll always be there on time...

Comment: But when will then be now?  Soon.

Comment: @NathanOliver Obviously now. Just another now.

Comment: @Servy How many days do I need to wait?

Comment: @felipe.zkn If you want a faster response, [contact the team directly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: I once did this by creating a test post that was about 100 blockquotes (actually probably way more).  Same kind of issue (though that resolved itself).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Open the JavaScript console of your favourite browser, go [to the Stack Overflow homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/), and execute the following code:

```js
jQuery.post('/post/discard-draft', {
    fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey,
    postType: 'ask',
});
```

Comment: Great solution!